# how to add the white border and 'peeling' shadow to a photo in Pages?

Tags: photos, pages

It's been a while since I used Pages, but the last time I used it, I dragged and dropped a photo into a blank document and there were options to add nice borders to the photo.

Specifically, I added an effect which made the photo look like it was peeling off the page on the left and right side, and there was a shadow underneath each corner giving it a 3d appearance.

I can't for the life of me find that feature in Pages (using Page '09).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the same effect you're looking for, but to apply different borders in Pages I followed these steps:

1. Place the picture where you want it in your document
2. Open the `Inspector` by holding <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
3. Go to the `Graphic` tab:
   [image]
4. Go to the `Stroke` menu and choose `Picture Frame` from the drop-down menu.
   [image]
5. Now you can choose a picture frame and alter its appearance by using the `Scale` slider.